# Group Policy for a Kiosk application

Tags: group-policy, application

I have a Windows application (WPF), which I have run in a Kiosk scenario, limiting the user's access to other functionalities except the application itself.

Reading this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479087.aspx here, I think **Group Policy** is probably the thing that would help here.

In here is explained to use a custom shell instead of windows explorer. My application will not be retail/enterprise application, but for a single computer. Is group policy the apt thing for this?

In addition, I wanted some suggestions to write the group policy for my application where I have restrict the user's access to loggin off, shutting down, Closing application/process, some mouse events etc. Kindly refer me to some place where I can read about the same to include my requirements in my custom shell, and then further on to deploy this group policy.

Comment: This is doable, although a lot to think about if you have never used Group Policy before. Is this kiosk machine joined to an Active Directory domain? If so, which version are your domain controllers running on, and what version of Windows is the kiosk?